# Dbeaver: Why does code not work correctly?

Tags: sql, dbeaver

It doesn't create all my tables and also says I have syntax errors. Can anyone help??

```
CREATE table project (
    project_id int not null,
    budget_id int not null,
    division_id int not null,
    project_name varchar(40),
    project_begin_date date,
    project_end_date date
);

ALTER table project
add constraint pk_project_project_id
primary key(project_id)
;

ALTER table project
add constraint fk_project_budget_id
foreign key(budget_id) references budget(budget_id)
;

ALTER table project
add constraint fk_project_division_id
foreign key (division_id) references division(division_id)
;

CREATE table division( 
    division_id  int not null,
    division_name varchar(40),
    
    constraint pk_division_division_id primary key(division_id)
);

CREATE table committee(
    committee id int not null,
    committee_name varchar(40),
    
    constraint pk_committee_committee_id primary key(committe_id)
);

create table employee( 
    employee_id int not null,
    given_name varchar(40),
    middle_name varchar(40),
    family_name varchar(40),
    form_of_address varchar(10),
    name_suffix varchar(25),
    work_phone_number varchar(20),
    hourly_budget_rate numeric(8,2),
    
    constraint pk_employee_employee_id primary key(employee_id)
);

CREATE  table budget(
    budget_id int not null,
    budget_description varchar(100),
    
    constraint pk_budget_budget_id primary key(budget_id)
);

CREATE  table section(
    section_id int not null,
    division_id int,
    budget_id int,
    section_name varchar(40),
    
    constraint pk_section_section_id primary key(section_id),
    constraint pk_section_buget_id foreign key(budget_id) references budget(budget_id),
    constraint pk_section_division_id foreign key(division_id) references division(division_id)
);



CREATE table employee_job_assignment( 
    job_assignment_id int not null,
    employee_id int not null,
    section_id int not null,
    begin_datetime date,
    end_datetime date,
    job_title varchar(100),
    
    constraint pk_employee_job_assignment primary key(job_assignment_id),
    constraint pk_employee_job_assignment foreign key(employee_id) references employee(employee_id),
    constraint pk_employee_job_assignment foreign key(section_id) references section(section_id)
);

CREATE  table budget_category(
    budget_category_code char(5),
    budget_category_description char(100),
    
    constraint pk_budget_category primary key(budget_category_code)
);

CREATE table budget_charge( 
    transaction_id int not null,
    budget_category_code char(5),
    budget_id int not null,
    transaction_date date,
    transaction_description varchar(100),
    transaction_type char(5),
    
    constraint pk_budget_charge_transaction_id primary key(transaction_id),
    constraint pk_budget_charge_budget_category_code foreign key(budget_category_code) references budget_category(budget_category_code),
    constraint pk_budget_charge_budget_id foreign key(budget_id) references budget(budget)
);

CREATE office(
    office_id int not null,
    office_type char(1),
    office_building char(5),
    office_location varchar(20),
    
    constraint pk_office primary key(office_id)
);

CREATE table employee_office(
    office id int not null,
    employee_id int not null,
    
    constraint pk_employee_office_office_id foreign key(office_id) references office(office_id),
    constraint pk_employee_office_employee_id foreign key(employee id) references employee(employee_id)
);

CREATE table project_employee(
    employee_id int not null,
    project_id int not null,
    project_role varchar(25),
    
    constraint pk_project_employee_employee_id foreign key(employee_id) references employee(employee_id),
    constraint pk_project_employee_project_id foreign key(project_id) references project(project_id)
);

CREATE table purchase_expense_charge(
    transaction_id int not null,
    purchase_expense_dollars numeric(8,2),
    
    constraint pk_purchase_expense_charge_transaction_id primary key(transaction_id),
    constraint pk_purchase_expense_charge_transaction_id foreign key(transaction_id) references budget_charge(transaction_id)
);

CREATE table hours_charge(
    transaction_id int not null,
    employee_id int not null,
    hours_charged numeric(7,2),
    time_period_begin_date date,
    time_period_end_date date,
    
    constraint pk_hours_charge_transaction_id primary key(transaction_id),
    constraint pk_hours_charge_transaction_id foreign key(transaction_id) references budget_charge(transaction_id),
    constraint pk_hours_charge_employee_id foreign key(employee_id) references employee(employee_id)
);

CREATE table budget_line_item(
    budget_category_code char(5),
    budget_id int not null,
    line_item_budget_dollars numeric(8,2),
    
    constraint pk_budget_line_item_budget_category_code foreign key(budget_category_code) references budget_category(budget_category_code),
    constraint pk_budget_line_item_budget_category_code foreign key(budget_id) references budget(budget_id)
);

CREATE table travel_expense_charge(
    transaction_id  int not null,
    employee_id int not null,
    trip_expense_dollars NUMERIC(8,2),
    trip_destination VARCHAR(100),
    trip_begin_date date,
    trip_end_date date,

    constraint pk_travel_expense_charge_transaction_id primary key (transaction_id),
    constraint pk_travel_expense_charge_transaction_id foreign key (transaction_id) references budget_charge(transaction_id),
    constraint pk_travel_expense_charge_employee_id foreign key (employee_id) references employee(employee_id)

);

CREATE table committee_member(  
    committee_id int not null,
    employee_id int not null,
    committee_role varchar(25),
    
    constraint pk_committee_member_committee_id foreign key(committee_id) references committee(committee_id)
    constraint pk_comittee_member_employee_id foreign key(employee id) references employee(employee_id)
);
```

Comment: What are the errors? SQL is a pretty good language in terms of telling you exactly what and where your problems are when you have them.

Comment: The foreign keys need to be added LAST after the tables that are declared in the `references` clause are created. There could be other issues, but start with that change first.